# Animation Nodes - Is it possible to add a texture image to a "target" Mesh Object Output node in Animation Nodes?

Tags: texturing, animation-nodes

I'm trying to add a texture image to a "target" Mesh Object Output node and have the texture follow and warp with it when I change the compose matrix. Is this possible?

I'm using Blender 2.83 and AN 2.1.7

Node setup:
[image: Node setup]

Image texture I'm trying to apply to the cylinder using the "target" Mesh Object Output node in Animation Nodes.
[image: Image texture I'm trying to apply to the cylinder.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks goes to OmarEmaraDev

In the Mesh Object Input node, there is a hidden input called Load UVs, enabling it should transfer the UV map and the texture should appear as you might expect.

[image: Shader setup]

[image: Animation node setup]